# Excel Vba Loop Date Format

Tags: excel, vba, loops

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range

    Set KeyCells = Range("P3")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then

        v = Range("Q3", Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Value
       
        'No of months e.g. 6 months or 1 year
        'Days = Range("P16").Value
        
        With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            For Each c In v
                .Item(c) = 1
            Next c
            Range("R3").Resize(.Count) = Application.Transpose(.Keys)
        End With
    
        MsgBox "Cell " & Target.Address & " has changed."

    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

I've tried the code above to get the unique name of months on column R as you can see on the image.

Now im trying to get the output including the year as per column S format with the correct year from column P

and would like to have a counter depending on the value of cell "P16" to add 28 days on the inputed date on "P3"

Comment: `Range(Target.Address)` is the same as `Target`

Comment: "the correct year" is the entered year (in Col P), or the current year?  P16 is months, or days?  What effect should changing values in P16 have exactly?

Comment: And what prevents you from doing it? If you understand the code you posted, you should be able to do it.

Comment: Im just a beginner coding in vba. I am just self studying. i got this code here in stack and trying to manipulate things for future reference.